# 2D Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, matrix, iterator, lambda

I wanted to play with a two-dimensional generic data container in C++ and explore different methods of traversals: using closures and iterators. I'd like a review of it.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    using array = std::vector<T>;
    using size = std::size_t;
    array data;
    size rows_;
    size cols_;

   public:
    Matrix(size rows, size cols)
        : data(cols * rows), rows_{rows}, cols_{cols} {}

    T &operator()(size row, size col) { return data[row * cols_ + col]; }

    const T &operator()(size row, size col) const {
        return data[row * cols_ + col];
    }

    int rows() const { return rows_; }
    int cols() const { return cols_; }

    void traverse(std::function<void(T &)> f) {
        for (auto &el : data) f(el);
    }

    void traverse(std::function<void(T &)> f, size row, size col) {
        for (auto &[rd, cd] : neighbours_delta) {
            int r = row + rd, c = col + cd;
            if (r >= 0 && r < rows_ && c >= 0 && c < cols_) f((*this)(r, c));
        }
    }

    typename array::iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    typename array::iterator end() { return data.end(); }

    auto neighbours(size row, size col) {
        return NeighbourIterator(row, col, *this);
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix &m) {
        for (int row = 0; row < m.rows_; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m.cols_; ++col) {
                os << m(row, col) << " ";
            }
            os << std::endl;
        }
        return os;
    }

   protected:
    std::pair<int, int> neighbours_delta[8] = {
        {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

    struct NeighbourIterator {
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T *;
        using reference = T &;

        NeighbourIterator(size row, size col, Matrix<T> &m, int neighbor = 0)
            : row{row}, col{col}, m{m}, neighbor{neighbor} {}

        auto get_delta() const { return m.neighbours_delta[neighbor]; }

        bool exists() {
            auto [rd, cd] = get_delta();
            int r = row + rd, c = col + cd;
            return r >= 0 && r < m.rows_ && c >= 0 && c < m.cols_;
        }

        T &get_neighbor() const {
            auto [rd, cd] = get_delta();
            return m(row + rd, col + cd);
        }

        reference operator*() const { return get_neighbor(); }
        pointer operator->() { return get_neighbor(); }
        NeighbourIterator &operator++() {
            do {
                neighbor++;
            } while (neighbor < 8 && !exists());
            return *this;
        }
        NeighbourIterator operator++(int) {
            NeighbourIterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        auto begin() { return NeighbourIterator(row, col, m, 0); }
        auto end() { return NeighbourIterator(row, col, m, 8); }

        friend bool operator==(const NeighbourIterator &a,
                               const NeighbourIterator &b) {
            return a.neighbor == b.neighbor;
        };
        friend bool operator!=(const NeighbourIterator &a,
                               const NeighbourIterator &b) {
            return a.neighbor != b.neighbor;
        };

       private:
        Matrix<T> &m;
        size row, col;
        int neighbor;
    };
};

int main() {
    Matrix<int> m(10, 10);

    // Can use STL algorithms
    std::fill(m.begin(), m.end(), 0);

    // Can use range-based for
    for (auto &el : m) el += 1;

    // Can use lambdas
    int sum = 0;
    m.traverse([&sum](int &el) { sum += el; });

    // Can use lambdas over neighbours
    m.traverse([](int &el) { el = 0; }, 5, 5);

    // Can use range-based for over neighbours
    for (auto &el : m.neighbours(8, 8)) el = 8;

    // Can display on cout
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `NeighbourIterator` feature looks inconsistent in several ways. Shouldn't the type be `public`, since we make objects of the type publicly accessible by `neighbours` method? If so, the meaning of the `neighbor` constructor parameter is unclear for class users. Should we bother users with checking of neighbor existence? Maybe the `_delta` and the order of neighbors are iterator's implementation details. It is a `struct` with `private` fields. Note that `begin` and `end` are non-static factory methods. They also traditionally belong to containers. I think that the design should be reconsidered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Enable compiler warnings and fix all warnings

When developing code, make it a habit of enabling strict compiler warnings, and fix all the warnings the compiler finds. My compiler complains about several issues:

- Comparison between signed and unsigned integers, because you use `int` for some variables and `size` for others. Be consistent, and always use the size type for indices and sizes. Of course you will have a problem then with relative offsets (like `neighbours_delta`). You might have to use `std::ptrdiff_t` here, and maybe cast appropriately at the right times. Be careful that the range of a signed type is different than that of an unsigned one.
- In `NeighbourIterator`, member variables appear to be initialized in a different order in the constructor than they are declared.

## Naming things

Be consistent when spelling things. I see you use both "neighbors" and "neighbours". It doesn't matter much which one you choose, as long as you are consistent. If you don't know which spelling to use, go for the American one.

## Be careful with type aliases

The words "array" and "vector" mean two different things in C++. By using the alias `array` for `std::vector<T>`, you might confuse C++ programmers. I would call it `container_type`, this follows the naming convention of the standard library.

Try to mimick the standard library as much as possible. Every STL container defines `size_type`. By doing the same, generic algorithms that want to access `size_type` will be able to work on your class as well. Have a look at how [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) do this. It seems you did do this for your iterator type.

You can make type aliases `public` as well.

## Try to make it work like STL containers as much as possible

To really make it a generic data container, it has to act as much as possible as other data containers. Have a look at other [STL containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), and implement all their details where possible. Consider member functions like `at()` and `swap()`, constant iterators via `cbegin()` and `cend()`, add a copy and move constructors and assignment operators. Add an `Allocator` template parameter and pass it on to the underlying `std::vector`.

## Remove `traverse()`

Yes, it makes applying a lambda to the matrix slightly easier, but consider that you already have iterators, so you can use a range-`for` loops or use algorithms like [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). This means this didn't add any new functionality, and instead just adds a burden on you to maintain this feature.

## Add more ways to iterate over the matrix

Contrary to `traverse()`, `neighbours()` is very useful. Consider that you also might want to iterate over rows and columns, and perhaps iterate over a submatrix.

Also note that you didn't provide `const` versions of `traverse()`.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary, and might impact performance.

## C++23 is coming

C++ has historically been a bit annoying when it comes to multi-dimensional arrays. However, [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) will offer significant improvements in this area. First is that it will allow for a [multi-dimensional subscript operator](https://wg21.link/P2128R6), so your `operator()` can be turned into an `operator[]`. Second, [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) will provide a multi-dimensional view of vectors and arrays. This would simplify your class a lot.

Comment: How would you name the iterators for the other type of iterators? Would `m.submatrix(x1, y1, x2, y2)` that is a subclass of Matrix featuring `begin()` and `end()` is a good choice?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a very good choice.

Answer (score 2):

## Good things

- Appropriate use of `const`.
- Pretty good user interface (though I agree `traverse()` is unnecessary).
- `neighbours()` iterator also works as a Range, and could be useful for implementing Conway's Game of Life.

## Improvements

In addition to [G. Sliepen's answer](/a/281247/75307):

### Matrix

- Add move constructor and assignment (implement using `std::swap()`).
- Add `operator>>(std::istream&)`.
- If `traverse()` were kept, we should have `const` versions too - more reason to remove it and stick with the iterators.
- I don't see any need for `neighbours_delta` to change - it could be `constexpr`.
- Instead of using a raw array, consider `std::array` for `neighbours_delta` - then you could use its `size()` instead of magic number 8 in many contexts.  It could instead be a member of `NeighbourIterator` if the `traverse()` of neighbours was removed, or rewritten to use the iterator.
- The presence of `protected` members suggests an intention to derive from this, so provide a `virtual` destructor (probably `= default`).
- `typename array::iterator begin()` can simply be `auto begin()`.
- Consider providing the other begin/end functions (const and/or reverse).

### NeighbourIterator

- Constructor should have its initializer list in the order that initialisation will occur.
- `!=` operator can be defined `= default`.  I think that `==` should also be default, as iterators referring to different matrices or positions are certainly unequal.
  Consider implementing `<=>` instead, since iterators are weakly ordered (strongly if from same matrix and position).
- Provide a `const_iterator`.  This can be done by templating `NeighbourIterator`, but there's a little trickiness to providing the conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator`.
- `->` should be `const`.  I don't understand how it calls `get_neighbour() const` as it stands.
- `begin()` can return an iterator that shouldn't be dereferenced.  I think this can be fixed without too much performance impact by skipping any invalid values in `get_neighbour()` or perhaps in the constructor (which to choose depends on how often you use `begin()` compared to dereferencing).  We'll still need to do the same advance in `++`, so that comparing to an end iterator still works.
- Provide the `--` operators, so it can be a bidirectional iterator.

### Future considerations

- Consider a representation that has a *stride¹* that's not necessarily the same as line length - that's useful for cropped views onto a larger matrix.
- Perhaps provide a `Point` type to index into it using `[]` operator.
- C++23 will allow templating on the type of `*this`, which will save you writing so many const/non-const overload pairs.

---

¹ Consider a matrix with *R* rows and *C* columns and a view on a sub-matrix of this (using the same storage of values), with *r* rows and *c* columns.  The sub-matrix mostly works using the same code - except that when we move from one row to the next, we need to advance by *C* positions in the storage, rather than by *c* positions.  In this case *C* is the "stride" value from row to row, and it's different from the line length *c*.

Comment: What are you referring to with the `stride representation`?

Comment: I've added a footnote explaining that - I hope it makes sense.